# In JavaScript, is there a way to programmatically allow the browser to receive user events inside an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dom-events, ecmascript-2016

I have an infinite loop that calls `foo`:

```
while(true) foo();
```

I want to insert a hook inside the code of `foo` that will allow the user to break the loop and I'm not allowed to modify the structure of the code: **I'm only allowed to modify the code of `foo`!**

I don't know how to do that using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

The trick I thought about was to call `confirm` inside `foo` and if the user chooses 'OK', `foo` will throw an exception:

```
function foo() {
   if (confirm('break the loop?')) {
     throw("Loop is broken");
   }
   // do stuff
}
while(true) foo();
```

It works, because `confirm` lets the browser check for pending events.

But the problem is that `confirm` is invasive. I'd prefer to run an event handler on the document. Something like this:

```
document.body.onkeydown =  function(e) {
  if(e.keyCode === 83 /*Ctrl-S*/) {
     window.breakTheLoop = true;
  }
};


function bar() {
   if (window.breakTheLoop) {
     throw("Loop is broken");
   }
}
while(true) bar();
```

But it doesn't work because the browser will never receive the `keydown` event.

So, is there a way in Javascript to tell the browser to check for pending user events?

Comment: If the loop is 100% synchronous, then it will never get to your event, because its processing the loop. JavaScript is single threaded so if you want this kind of behavior you need to either break the loop into asynchronous (which you apparently don't want) or forcefully create a new processing thread, using something like webworkers: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/. Be advised that webworkers requires a lot of setup and doesn't have the best cross-browser support yet.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen it's not 100% true. `confirm` allows to break the loop. I'm looking for something like a silent `confirm`.

Comment: The single-threaded nature of Javascript means you can't do what you're asking, unless you allow the browser time to process something else.  Your aversion to timeouts or intervals is your problem here.  Maybe if you could explain why you don't want to use them then we could help you with that instead, because this approach will not work.

Comment: `I'm looking for something like a silent confirm` it's called `setTimeout`. Which you said you don't want to use. As stated,  it's impossible to satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I've re-read the question three times and it always seems you need `setInterval`. What is the reason to use a loop here? What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to accomplish it this way? Is this an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: What is purpose of infinite loop? What does `foo` do?

Comment: Ugh, if you literally have to do that "programatically" (without user prompts), then you'll have to hack it and throw an exception to get out or something. The requirements are, quite frankly, a bit insane. It seems like somebody who knows C decided to design a JS program. You might be able to use Web workers, I guess, they run in a separate thread but I'm not sure how feasable that would be. Again, everything in the main thread will be blocked by that `while`. And the browser runs the main UI loop in a single thread. That means nothing would work - no animations, no interaction, no nothing.

Comment: The simple answer to your question is "no". Your requirements were given to you by someone who doesn't understand how Javascript works in browsers.

Comment: What is the reason for a `while(true)`? Do you **want** to block the UI thread? You say you can only control `foo` and if you want `foo` to block the UI thread until such a time where `foo`'s execution has ended by user event, then you need to `prompt` or `confirm` from within `foo`. It is the only, synchronous way. (If we disregards things like webworkers)

Comment: To understand how the JavaScript is executed in the browser, read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop .

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible. JavaScript is one-threaded language (almost one threaded, read the specs). In browsers the only synchronous user inputs are `prompt` and `confirm`. All other user events are asynchronous, which mean that if user press some key, for example, a new event will be put inside event queue. The main thread can reach and process it only when the current executing event is finished.

All synchronous loops (while, for, forEach, etc) must be processed to end or broken before next event will be processed. There is no way to do what you want and there is such a proof which you can find if you read the specs. Even in ES7 there is no way to do it. Do not wait for answer you want, because nobody can do it.

However, I wrote a silly code (do not take it seriously) which at first sight do what you want (but actually it is a joke):

```
foo();

function foo(){
  window.truе = false; // Override true
  onkeydown = a => a.keyCode - 32 || alert('The loop is broken.');
}

while(truе) foo(); // This should not be changed
```

Basically, we are here overriding default `true` value, so we can manipulate the `while` loop. Do not believe this works? See the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ok1zwjc/).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm only allowed to modify the code of foo!
>
> I don't know how to do that using setTimeout or setInterval.

`while` loop is not necessary to return expected result. You can use `Promise` constructor, `setTimout` with no `duration` set, recursion. 
Set a variable to a `Boolean` value, at `.keydown` event set variable to opposite `Boolean`. Check for value of variable within `setTimeout` at `Promise` resolver function. If varible is `true`, return a value to `.then()`, return `foo` recursively from `.then()`. Else call `reject()` with new `Error` to stop recursion, handle error, possibly start process again at `.catch()`.

Note `Ctrl+S` opens `Save File` dialog. Substituted `32` : `Space` key for `83`.

```js
let prop = false;

let foo = (n) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      if (prop === false) resolve(n);
      else reject(new Error("foo stopped"))
   })
  }).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      return foo(++n)
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
}

document.body.onkeydown = (e) => {
 if (e.keyCode === 32) prop = true;
}

foo(0);
```

```css
body {
  width:90vw;
  height:90vw;
  border: 4px solid sienna;
}
```

```html
Press Space key to stop foo
```